# Как развернуть 2 приложения на 1 Ip-адресе?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

Проект: Ubuntu + Nginx + Flask + Gunicorn + wsgi.

Логика такая:

- 1ое приложения - рабочее
- 2ое приложение - тестовое(другая БД, другие ссылки c префиксами)

Оба слушают 1 IP-адрес, но разные ссылки на нем.

Создал другую БД, добавил префикс к ссылкам для 2го приложения, но не запускаются сразу 2 приложения. Сначала запускается 1, потом когда отрубишь его - запускается другое. Сразу оба не работают. Как сделать чтобы работали сразу оба?

**Файл wsgi.py:**

```
from myproject import MyApp as app
from test_project import Test_App as test_app
import threading

if __name__ == "__main__":
    aps1 = threading.Thread(target=app.run(port=5000, debug=False)).start()
    aps2 = threading.Thread(target=test_app.run(port=5001, debug=False)).start()
```

Comment: Поставить вебсервер (nginx, haproxy, apache, и т.п.) и настроить роутинг.

Comment: гляньте [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1324978/209304), я уже задавался таким вопросом. Может поможет. На уровне nginx все реализуется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же сразу функцию вызываете в основном потоке `app.run(port=5000, debug=False)`. А в поток в качестве `target` передаёте результат этой функции. Вот оно и ждёт завершения функции `app.run()` прежде чем аналогично будет позвана `test_app.run()`.
Попробуйте так:

```
    aps1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: app.run(port=5000, debug=False)).start()
    aps2 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: test_app.run(port=5001, debug=False)).start()
```